# Removing comma from the string in rdlc

Tags: string, rdlc

How to remove comma from the end of a string in RDLC text box formula field?

Here is the expression:

```
=Fields!Titles.Value
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're sure there won't be any other commas (and are okay with removing all of them), you can replace the commas with nothing, like this:

```
=Replace(Fields!Titles.Value, ",", "")
```

If there could be commas elsewhere in the fields that you don't want to remove (and you want to remove commas occurring at the end of the field *only*), you could do something like this:

```
=iif(Right(Fields!Titles.Value, 1) = ",", 
     Left(Fields!Titles.Value, Len(Fields!Titles.Value)-1),
     Fields!Titles.Value)
```

If there can be whitespace before or after the comma, you'll need to add handling for that also (use `Trim`, `LTrim`, and `RTrim` as needed for your situation).

Comment: yes I used this: Left(Fields!Titles.Value, Len(Fields!Titles.Value)-1) ... Thanks